# Theano: Where to put .theanorc file for Anaconda installation? (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, anaconda, theano

I recently installed Python 2.7 using Anaconda on my Windows 10 (x64)

I am trying to install Theano, I am however not sure where I should put the '.theanorc' file (for setting Theano parameters). I have verified that theano works (trained small neural network).

I have tried to put it in `C:\Anaconda` (where `python.exe` and `\Lib\os.py` are located), but it doesn't seem like theano registers it.

My `.theanorc` file

```
[global]
floatX=float32
```

When I type

```
>>> import theano; print(theano.config)
```

I get

```
...
floatX (('float64', 'float32', 'float16'))
    Doc:  Default floating-point precision for python casts.

Note: float16 support is experimental, use at your own risk.
    Value:  float64
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dotfiles are typically stored in the `%HOME%` directory, which on windows is `%USERPROFILE%`. This translates to `C:\Users\username`